# After changing Application language showTimePicker dialog comes with 24 hour in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using `showTimePicker` in my application. Also, I am using [Internationalizing](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) for my flutter app with two languages(English '**en**' & Spanish '**es**').

- **Code for present showTimePicker:**

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: MaterialButton(
                minWidth: double.infinity,
                onPressed: () async {
                  TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                      return MediaQuery(
                        data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                            .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  S.of(context).set_time,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 14),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Issue what I am facing is Initially when I run my App with the English language it's working fine and showing **timePicker** with 12 hours formate. But when I am changing App language to Spanish from the App then it will start showing **timePicker** with 24 hours formate. Please find the below screenshots for the same.

**1.  When App language is English:**

[image]

**2.  When App language changed to Spanish:**

[image]

I am facing this issue while I change `supportedLocales` value to `Locale('es', '')` from `Locale('en', '')`. But I have no idea how I can fix this.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, have you found a solution in all that time?

Comment: @Talked Yes, I fixed these issues using the ```flutter_rounded_date_picker``` library. Also added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above issues as I found one library([flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker)) and using it, I am able to fix my problem. It is not a solution but we can use it as a workaround.

**Code for ShowTimer:**

```
 TimeOfDay picked = await showRoundedTimePicker(
                        context: context,
                        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor:Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                        locale: Locale("en", "")
);
```

As shown in the above code using [flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker) we can pass the locale and I am passing Locale`("en", "")` for Spanish and English. So It is showing 12 hours `timePicker` for any locale.

- For more information, you can refer [GitHub issue[54839]](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54839) raised by me

Comment: wow thanks man I'll try!
I have days with this problem

Answer (score 2):

```
final dateTime = await showTimePicker(
          context: context,
          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
          builder: (context, child) {
            if (MediaQuery.of(context).alwaysUse24HourFormat) {
              return child;
            } else {
              return Localizations.override(
                context: context,
                locale: Locale('en', 'US'),
                child: child,
              );
            }
      },
    );
```

Comment: This works for the dialog, but unfortunately also sets the local to en-US for the rest of the app

Answer (score 0):

With the  [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package, I can set both the language selection and the time zone as I wish.

**Here try this**

```
  FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
        format: DateFormat("HH:mm", "tr"), //!24 saat
        controller: timeTextController,
        locale: const Locale('tr', 'TR'),
        enableInteractiveSelection: true,
        initialTime: selectedTime,
        //locale: const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'tr'),
        resetIcon: Icon(Icons.close),
        validators: [
          FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "Lütfen Saat seçiniz")
        ],
        attribute: "time",
        inputType: InputType.time,
        alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
        timePickerInitialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
        decoration:
            UIHelperDecoration.inputDecoration(null, null, null, null),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Localizations.override(
            context: context,
            locale: Locale('tr', 'TR'),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with this method. I hope it helps.

=> Write your language here where it says 'tr_TR'

```
_showTimePicker(BuildContext context, ReminderViewModel viewModel) {
    return showTimePicker(
        initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                  alwaysUse24HourFormat:
                      'tr_TR' == context.locale.toString() ? true : false),
              child: child!);
        },
        cancelText: '',
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay(
            hour: int.parse(viewModel.startTime.split(":")[0]),
            minute: int.parse(viewModel.startTime.split(":")[1].split('')[0])));
  }
```